# Must the .equals method for objects be overriden for instances of that object type in order for them to be used as keys in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am having trouble with Hashmaps. Currently, my HashMap is a HashMap of an enum called `Names`, using a key of `Key Signatures`, or `HashMap<KeySignature, Names>`. Currently, the Name Enum stores values of KeySignatures, or `C_FLAT_MAJOR(new KeySignature(7, Accidental.FLAT, Scale.MAJOR);`. To get the Enum version of a given KeySignature, I've created the HashMap explained above:

```
private static final HashMap<KeySignature, Names> lookup = new HashMap<KeySignature, Names>();
static {
    for (Names name : Names.values()){
    lookup.put(new KeySignature(name.getKeySig()), name);

    }
}
```

So, when I need to check what is the Enum version of a KeySignature, I call a method, located in the KeySignature class:

```
public Names getCommonName() {
    return Names.lookup.get(this);

    }
```

However, the value returned is always null.

I cannot figure out what is causing this, but is seems as if the `HashMap.get()` method is comparing the key and the argument by reference rather than value. Do I have to override the .equals and .hash methods of KeySignature, or am I looking in the entirely wrong direction?

Comment: Yes you have to define manily `equals` in `KeySignature`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.

If you are going to create instances of `KeySignature` on the fly, then the `equals` method needs to compare them "by value".  The default implementation of `equals` simply tests to see if the objects are `==`.  So, you need get the hashmap to work, you need to override the default `equals` AND `hashcode` methods.

The other alternative would be to replace your code that creates new instances of `KeySignature` with alternative code that looks up an existing `KeySignature` instance for the given combination of note, Accidental and Scale.